# Brands filter widget for woocommerce/ bulk method to add atribute to several products

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am using [Perfect Brands for WooCommerce](https://wordpress.org/plugins/perfect-woocommerce-brands/) plugin
to put a brand filter in the WooCommerce widget.

Everything works ok, **but it doesn't filter my brands** ...

I found another plugin that links to attributes, but instead I can't find a bulk method to add a brand attribute to several products at once.

Anybody have any recommendations or solutions?

Comment: Change your plugin : https://www.frip.in/woocommerce-brands-plugin/

Comment: I would prefer a free version, from that list I tried the free ones and the brand filter does not work on the store page